# Use 'in' in an array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have a list of lists, so a two dimensional array. I'm trying to use `in` to figure out if a string is in these arrays. So instead of doing `if word in wordlist:`, I'm using:

```
for i in range(len(wordlist)):
   if word in wordlist[i]:
      wordlist[i][2] += 1 #this accounts for the frequency of a word in a file
if (i + 1 == len(wordlist) and word !=wordlist[len(wordlist)-1]):
   wordlist.append([word,linenum,1])
```

Is there a more graceful way of doing this?

Edit:
Sample `wordlist`:

`[['civilizati', 1, 1], ['of', 1, 1], ['science', 2, 1], ['is', 2, 1], ['knowledge', 3, 1], ['is', 3, 1]]`

Edit edit:

I think I wasn't clear in my question. If I were using a 1d list, I could do something like this:

```
if(word in wordlist1d):
   print("It's here")
else:
   wordlist1d.append(word)
```

This is much more graceful than my `for` loop monstrosity. However, since wordlist is not 1d, the statement word in wordlist never returns true, even if word is in a sublist of wordlist. I'm wondering if there is a more graceful way of doing that than using that `for` loop.

Comment: Are you getting the strings which have your string as a substring? Please explain what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: It might help if you post a small example of your wordlist.

Comment: Your inner lists appear to be `word, line, count` triples, so probably `in` is not needed to test (you only want to test against the `word` part).

Comment: @Blckknght I guess using in would add to the order of the problem, wouldn't it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing a loop with an `else` clause:

```
for sublist in wordlist:
    if word == sublist[0]:  # compare directly with the relevant part of the sublist
        sublist[2] += 1
        break  # we only will match at most once, so break after finding one
else:    # this clause is run if no break was hit
    wordlist.append([word, linenum, 1])
```

A more efficient approach might be to use a dictionary mapping from words to `lineno, count` sublists. Searching a dictionary is `O(1)`, rather than `O(n)` to search your list of lists. In order to make the code work for words that are not found, you can use the `setdefault` method:

```
d = {}
for word, lineno in document:
    d.setdefault(word, [lineno, 0])[1] += 1 # works whether or not word was in d before
```

Comment: Is this legal? This is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: @JFA: Is what legal? The `else`? That's legal, though it may confuse folks who are more used to other languages that don't have `else` clauses on their loops. [Check out the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using an index pointer and using it to iterate over the list, just iterate over the list directly:

```
for item in wordlist:
    if word in item:
        ....
```

Just to prove they're identical:

```
In [2]: for item in wordlist:
   ...:     print item
   ...:
['civilizati', 1, 1]
['of', 1, 1]
['science', 2, 1]
['is', 2, 1]
['knowledge', 3, 1]
['is', 3, 1]

In [3]: for i in range(len(wordlist)):
   ...:     print wordlist[i]
   ...:
['civilizati', 1, 1]
['of', 1, 1]
['science', 2, 1]
['is', 2, 1]
['knowledge', 3, 1]
['is', 3, 1]
```

What you want - now that you've provided your data format - is

```
for item in wordlist:
    if word == item[0]:
        item[2] += 1
```

Comment: +1 That certainly is graceful.  And clean.  And pretty fast.  And easy to understand.  And is the intended way to do it :-)

Comment: Actually, this is not compatible with the `if`statement, which depends on the output of i.

Comment: No, it is _exactly_ equivalent to your code. See above.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor Maybe I'm mistaken then. Where is the second `if` statement in your code? I want to find out if the word is in the list, or if I have to add it. It seems like you're saying my `for` loop and your `for` loop are identical, which is true. However, after your `for` loop, there is no second case which plans for the eventuality that I have to add words to the list.

Comment: I don't think it's doing what you think it is. What you had was effectively `if (True and word != last_word_in_wordList)`.

Comment: Ah, I apologize then, because I didn't explain myself well enough. I'm parsing a text document to find word frequency and what line the word first appears on. The sample wordlist is the final wordlist, and as I review it, it was from non-working code it seems. So I'm continually either checking to see if the word is in the list, or adding words to the list. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: The selected answer should work for you then, but I also highly recommend using `Counter` if possible.

Comment: That seems to be a popular opinion. I think that would be frowned upon for this assignment, as would using a dict, but I'll keep `Collections` in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off using a `dict` with the words as keys, and `[linenum, count]` pairs as values.  Your entire function becomes simply:

```
wordlist.setdefault(word, [linenum, 0])[1] += 1
```

If you have to turn this into a list, you can do:

```
[[k] + v for k, v in wordlist.items()]
```

Comment: You might be right. I was reading that if I change values in a dict though, it might not update correctly? This was in the pydoc. Any idea what this means?

Comment: You can't change the keys, but you can change the values

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for word counts in file, you can do:

```
from collections import Counter
wordlist = Counter(myfile.read().split())
```

If you want to get all words in the file, you can do:

```
wordlist.keys()
```

if you want to get count of partical word:

```
wordlist['myword']
```